# Define static size of an STL Container using custom allocator template

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, templates, memory-management, stl

I have been working on a program that shall allow saving and loading states of processes.
To eliminate some memory leaks I thought that deciding the number of items the STL containers can contain during their initialization would be useful.
I based my solution on the answers of [Rebinding in a custom STL allocator with pre-allocated block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15488527/rebinding-in-a-custom-stl-allocator-with-pre-allocated-block) and [STL Container: Constructor's Allocator parameter and scoped allocators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12556638/stl-container-constructors-allocator-parameter-and-scoped-allocators).
However, being limited to VS2010 due to project-defined restraint, I cannot take advantage of all the c++11 features.
Something is however wrong with my adaption, and I spent a few weeks trying to figure it out, but I can't, this is my first time attempting an allocator.

When I try to build it, I get this error:

```
error C2664: 'StaticAllocator<T,szSlots>::StaticAllocator(const StaticAllocator<T,szSlots> &) throw()' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'StaticAllocator<T,szSlots>' to 'const StaticAllocator<T,szSlots> &'
```

The detailed output shows:

```
error C2664: 'StaticAllocator<T,szSlots>::StaticAllocator(const StaticAllocator<T,szSlots> &) throw()' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'StaticAllocator<T,szSlots>' to 'const StaticAllocator<T,szSlots> &'
      with
      [
          T=std::_Container_proxy,
          szSlots=2
      ]
      and
      [
          T=int,
          szSlots=2
      ]
      and
      [
          T=std::_Container_proxy,
          szSlots=2
      ]
      Reason: cannot convert from 'StaticAllocator<T,szSlots>' to 'const StaticAllocator<T,szSlots>'
      with
      [
          T=int,
          szSlots=2
      ]
      and
      [
          T=std::_Container_proxy,
          szSlots=2
      ]
      No user-defined-conversion operator available that can perform this conversion, or the operator cannot be called
```

I am missing something, but not entirely sure what or how to go about implementing it.

My custom allocator looks like this, and is only meant to work with vector: (StaticAllocator.h)

```
#pragma once

#include <string.h>
#include <memory>

template <class T, size_t szSlots = 0>
class StaticAllocator
{
private:
    size_t szSlotsAllocated;
    size_t szSlotsInUse;
    size_t szSlotSize;
    T* array;

public:
    typedef T                   value_type;
    typedef value_type*         pointer;
    typedef const value_type*   const_pointer;
    typedef value_type&         reference;
    typedef const value_type&   const_reference;
    typedef std::size_t         size_type;
    typedef std::ptrdiff_t      difference_type;

    StaticAllocator()
    {
        if(szSlots > 0) array = new T(szSlots);
        szSlotsAllocated = szSlots;
        szSlotsInUse = 0;
        szSlotSize = sizeof(T);
    }

    StaticAllocator(const StaticAllocator& alloc) throw()
    {
        if(alloc.szSlotsAllocated > 0)
        {
            array = new T[alloc.szSlotsAllocated];
            memcpy(array, alloc.array, alloc.szSlotsAllocated * alloc.szSlotSize);
        }
        szSlotsAllocated = alloc.szSlotsAllocated;
        szSlotsInUse = alloc.szSlotsInUse;
        szSlotSize = alloc.szSlotSize;
    }

    template<class U>
    StaticAllocator(const StaticAllocator<U>& alloc) throw()
    {
        // Pray?
        if(alloc.szSlotsAllocated > 0)
        {
            (U*)array = new U(alloc.szSlotsAllocated);
            memcpy(array, alloc.array, alloc.szSlotsAllocated * alloc.szSlotSize);
        }
        szSlotsAllocated = alloc.szSlotsAllocated;
        szSlotsInUse = alloc.szSlotsInUse;
        szSlotSize = alloc.szSlotSize;
    }

    ~StaticAllocator()
    {
        if(szSlotsAllocated > 0) delete [] array;
    }    

    template<class U>
    struct rebind
    {
        typedef StaticAllocator<U, szSlots> other;
    };

    pointer address(reference x) const
    {
        return &x;
    }
    const_pointer address(const_reference x) const
    {
        return &x;
    }

    pointer allocate (size_type n, const_pointer hint = 0)
    {
        if((szSlotsInUse + n) < szSlotsAllocated)
        {
            pointer rv = &(array[szSlotsInUse]);
            szSlotsInUse += n;
            return rv;
        }
        throw std::bad_alloc();
    }

    void deallocate (pointer p, size_type n)
    {
        if((szSlotsInUse - n) < 0) szSlotsInUse = 0;
        else szSlotsInUse -= n;
    }

    size_type max_size() const throw()
    {
        return szSlotsAllocated;
    }

    void construct (pointer p, const_reference val)
    {
        p = value_type(val); // Can memcpy be used instead? (memcpy(p, val, szSlotSize);)
    }

    void destroy (pointer p)
    {
        p->~value_type();
    }
};
```

Demo program that causes the compilation error:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <vector>

#include "StaticAllocator.h"

int main(void)
{
    std::vector<int, StaticAllocator<int, 2>> iVec;
    iVec.push_back(3);
    iVec.push_back(5);

    printf("contents: %i and %i.\n", iVec[0], iVec[1]);
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: Use a proper placement new: `::new(p) value_type(val)`

Comment: How does informing the containers their maximum size at initialization prevent memory leaks? A vector will delete its own memory no matter what the size.

Comment: As Howard Hinnant put it in his answer to [the question you linked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15488527/rebinding-in-a-custom-stl-allocator-with-pre-allocated-block), "Said slightly differently, the C++ committee has effectively specified that allocators are reference types: copies are equivalent and point to the same memory pool." Your allocator doesn't satisfy that.

Comment: Also, your converting constructor is wrong. In `StaticAllocator(const StaticAllocator<U>& alloc)`, `StaticAllocator<U>` is `StaticAllocator<U, 0>`, which is not what you want.

Comment: Thanks for the replies so far, they have given me stuff to think about. I definitely need to re-think the memory allocation.  @Neil Kirk: The idea is to give the containers a pre-decided amount of memory to occupy. Say I limit a vector to 2, then it will not be able to allocate beyond 2 objects before getting "out of memory" responses. I don't need to disable the vector from deleting it's own memory, I only need to make sure it will re-use the same memory region. If I am thinking correctly, it'll allow me to capture the entire state of the vector, without leaking memory by losing allocations.